# Drupal 7, menu link to filter a view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I thought this would be easy, but I just can't figure it out.  I am bringing in a feed from audible, various book titles.

I have a view displaying the titles as needed.

I have a created a menu of categories-- fiction, romance, etc.

So I want to link the menu items to the view which is in a block and have it filter the block.  So for example, if I click on the romance link, it calls the view and filters out the romance related books.  There is a category field included in my view.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using those two modules

[Menu Node API](https://drupal.org/project/menu_node)

[Menu Node Views](https://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views)